# Tengo problemas en formular la ecuación siguiente en python

Tags: python

La ecuación es la siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que no estoy seguro si mi función (Y) definida en el código es la ecuación que estoy buscando. El programa que estoy haciendo es para calcular raíces con el metodo de bisección. Es el siguiente:

```
#Función para polinomios
def poli(x):
    y=6 + (3 * pow(x,2)) + (2 * pow(x,2))
    return (y)

#Toma de valores y acumuladores
xinf= 1
xsup= 2
iter=0
xr= (xinf+xsup)/2
error=1000
es=.005
print("{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10}".format("i","xinf","xsup","xr","signo","cambio","error"))
#Programa principal
while (error >= es):
    iter=iter+1
    xr= (xinf+xsup)/2
    test= poli(xinf)*poli(xr)
    if test <0:
        xsup=xr
        signo="negativo"
        limite="superior"
    elif test >0:
        xinf=xr
        signo="positivo"
        limite="inferior"
    else:
        error=0
    if iter >1:
        error= abs((xr-xrold)/xr)*100
    xrold=xr
    print("{:^10}{:^10.4f}{:^10.4f}{:^10.4f}{:^10}{:^10}{:^10.4f}".format(iter, xinf, xsup, xr, signo, limite,float(error)))
print("La raiz es:", xr)
```

Comment: ¿Donde está el lado izquierdo de la ecuación? Parece que tu función evalúa sólo el lado derecho (la parte del polinomio), por lo que la solución que encuentre será aquella para la que el polinomio valga cero, y no en la que sea igual al lado izquierdo de la ecuación. Lo que tienes que implementar en la función (que no debería llamarse `poli()`, por tanto) sería la resta de ambos lados, de modo que cuando esa resta valga cero (que es lo que buscas luego por bisección), la ecuación se cumplirá.

Comment: Por otro lado ¿tendrás bien copiado el segundo miembro de la ecuación? No veo mucho sentido a tener 3x^2 + 2x^2, ya que puede simplificarse a 5x^2